# Concatenar char de un arreglo en C

Tags: c, array

Tengo un puntero `char` con **números**, que sería:
`puntero = [1,2,4,5,\n,2,3,\n,5,2,1];`

¿Cómo puedo hacer que sea lo siguiente?:

`nuevo = [1245,\n,23,\n,521];`, `\n` es un salto de linea, es solo para representarlo.

He probado hacer un ciclo con `strcat` y `strtol`, pero no da resultados.

Comment: cuando pones 1245, te refieres al numero o al literal "1245" ?

Comment: literal, luego lo transformo a entero. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No has puesto código así que voy a hacer suposiciones.

Cuando dices que tienes un arreglo de Char con números entiendo que tienes esto:

```
char numeros[] ={'1','2','4','5','\n','2','3','\n','5','2','1'};
```

Y que lo que quieres conseguir es esto:

```
char **resultado = {"12345","23","521"};
```

En el primer caso tienes caracteres sueltos. Cada carácter es individual y no está relacionado con ningún otro. Sin embargo, en el segundo caso tienes tres cadenas de caracteres.

Si has estudiado cadenas de caracteres sabrás que las cadenas han de finalizar con un carácter nulo.

Aplicando esto puedes resolver el problema en tres cómodos pasos:

- Copias tu arreglo de tamaño *N* en otro de tamaño *N+1*.
- En la posición *N* del nuevo arreglo escribes un carácter nulo.
- Recorres el nuevo arreglo y sustituyes los saltos de línea por caracteres nulos.

Dicho con código podría quedar así:

```
char numeros[11] ={'1','2','4','5','\n','2','3','\n','5','2','1'};
char resultado[12];
resultado[11]='\0';
memcpy(resultado,numeros,11);

for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
{
  if(resultado[i]=='\n')
    resultado[i]='\0';
}
```

Para imprimir las cadenas basta con localizar los caracteres nulos... Después de cada carácter nulo se encuentra el inicio de una de las cadenas buscadas:

```
printf("%s\n",resultado);
for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
{
  if(resultado[i]=='\0')
    printf("%s\n",&resultado[i+1]);
}
```

Si trabajas con memoria dinámica la cosa cambia ligeramente, pero como no das más detalles...

Un saludo

Comment: Efectivamente, trabajo con memoria dinámica, probare lo que propone. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto te sirva:

```
    char puntero[] = {'1','2','4','5'}; // Tu arreglo
    char nuevo[500][50]; // Tu nuevo arreglo de strings
    char str[500]; // Auxiliar para concatenar los caracteres
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) // Concateno los caracteres
        str[i] = puntero[i];

    strcpy(nuevo[0], str); // Lo agrego al arreglo nuevo
    printf("%s\n", nuevo[0]); // Probamos que haya salido bien
```

Obviamente vas a tener que adecuarlo a tu programa con los ciclos y algoritmos correspondientes para cortar en el '\n', etc. Esto es solo demostrativo.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias, lo probare :)